# Equivalent code for UPDATE with JOIN in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I have the following UPDATE and would like to convert it for an **Entity Framework** equivalent code (dotnet core 5):

```
UPDATE A
   SET A.Value = A.Value + B.AnotherValue
  FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON (B.Status = 'A' AND B.Code = A.Code)
```

Is there any way to do this without foreach, while, etc?

Comment: Why the restriction on not using loops?  Remember, EF is not SQL.  You could do this using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` so that it uses EF connections.

Comment: There is no specific restriction.
I just thought there was a way to do it without loops.
If the search result is 1000 records, for example, it may be slow.

Comment: Linq the left side of an equation you can only change every item.  Your query has restrictions (B.Status = 'A' AND B.Code = A.Code).  So if you do not use a loop then left side of equation will only have some of the items where (B.Status = 'A' AND B.Code = A.Code).